# RegEx Expression to find strings with quotation marks and a backslash

Tags: regex

I am using a program that pastes what is in the clipboard in a modified format according to what I specify.

I would like for it to paste paths (i.e. "C:\folder\My File") without the pair of double quotes.

This, which isn't using RegEx works: Find " (I simply enter than in one line) and replace with nothing. I enter nothing in the second field. I leave it blank.

Now, though that works, it will remove double quotes in this scenario: Bob said "What are you doing?"

I would like the program to remove the quotes only if the the words enclosed in the double quotes have a backslash.

So, once again, just to make sure I am clear, I need the following:

1) RegEx Expression to find strings that have both double quotes and a backslash within those set of quotes.

2) A RegEx Expression that says: replace the backslashes with backslashes (i.e. leave them there).

Thank you for the fast response. This program has two fields. One for what to find and the other for what to replace. So, what would go in the 2nd field?

[image]

The program came with the Remove HTML entry, which has
<[^>]*> in the match pattern
and nothing (it's blank) in the Replacement field.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which language you use, here's an example in Javascript:

```
> s = 'say "hello" and replace "C:\\folder\\My File" thanks'
"say "hello" and replace "C:\folder\My File" thanks"
> s.replace(/"([^"\\]*\\[^"]*)"/g, "$1")
"say "hello" and replace C:\folder\My File thanks"
```

Comment: Is not `/"([^"]*\\[^"]*)"/` sufficient?

Comment: @kajic: can be, but I like to be explicit ;)

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. This program has two fields. One for what to find and the other for what to replace. You can view a screenshot here: http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/2583/nuqe.jpg

So, what would go in the 2nd field?

Comment: @Rolo: no idea, but I've added these details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in .NET:

```
^".*?\\.*?"$
```